# How can I tell python to use 64bit java?

Tags: java, python, 64-bit, 32-bit

In windows command line, if I type `java -version`, I get

```
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

and `python -v`

```
#snip
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

In python if use

`call("java -version")`

I get

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Is there a way I can force my python to use the 64bit JVM?

Comment: Why are you calling java from python? And why do you want to call the x64?

Comment: @Kyllopardiun The java is a core program that needs to run, and it needs to be x64 to use all the memory. The python is just a utility script telling it when to run.

Comment: Have you tried os.system("#command") instead of call? As it is a system call you should be able to get the x64 version.

Comment: @Kyllopardiun - os.system("java -version") gives the 32bit JVM

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo "Error: This Java instance does not support a 64-bit JVM.
Please install the desired version."

Comment: Do you have two different Java installations on your system? Maybe one in `Program Files (x86)` and one in `Program Files`?

Comment: @cyon - yes - there appears to be multiple java installations. How would i specify which to use?

Comment: I know it's a cheap workaround, but have you tried to use the python to call a bat which calls the java?  

Or: can you use a bat to call both of them?

Comment: @Kyllopardiun - Actually, the python _is_ calling a .bat, which calls java, but that doesn't solve it. Yes, the alternative is calling the python from a .bat, which I'm looking at, but I'd rather try solve it this way first.

Comment: @dwjohnston Well, you could attempt to investigate the `PATH` variables in python to see why it is different to the one in your command line. Or you could just hardcode the absolute path of the 64 bit Java.

Comment: Maybe: *"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_21\\bin\\java -version"* the jdk numbers might be different on your machine

Comment: @cyon Hardcoding the absolute path the 64bit java works, do you want to post that as answer? `call("\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\java.exe\" -version")`

Comment: You appear to have two versions of Java, a 32-bit update 25 and a 64-bit update 7.  I would remove both and install 64-bit update 51.  If this doesn't default to the server version you can use `-server` to specify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `java -version` in your windows command line it will consult the `PATH` environment variable to locate the `java` executable.

`subprocess.call` which I assume you are using there seems to not use that same windows `PATH` variable on Windows in your case. Perhaps if you enforced that it spawns a shell (which is not considered safe according to the docu) it would work.

```
call("java -version", shell=True)
```

In case you have multiple Java installations (i.e a 64 bit and 32 bit JRE), the easiest solution would be to hardcode the absolute path to your java 64 bit executable

```
call("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\java -version")
```